# Why is secret_key_base blank on Heroku (Rails 5.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I deleted `secrets.yml` and created `credentials.yml.enc`.

Locally I am using `master.key`, and in production I don't have any master key, only a `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` set as an environment variable.

On Heroku, if I run `Rails.application.secrets` I get:

```
{:secret_key_base=>nil, :secret_token=>nil}
```

and if I run `Rails.application.credentials` I do in fact see my `secret_key_base`.

However, locally... if I run the same commands, I **DO** see `secret_key_base` when calling `Rails.application.secrets`.

My main concern is that rails is going to have an empty `secret_key_base` in production which would be used to encrypt sessions and all kinds of critically important security things. I'm trying to verify that it actually does have the key set.

I'd love a way to 100% confirm that it's working in production, and that it's not blank. Is there some method I can call to check which doesn't rely on calling it via the methods above?

Answer (score 0):

The SECRET_KEY_BASE is stored as an environment variable on Heroku. You can either view these in the interface by going to the settings for that dyno or you can do it in the terminal:

`heroku run bash`

then

`env | grep SECRET_KEY_BASE`

If you do not see it there may be an issue but you can generate a new one for Heroku and set it in the environment variables (see `Rails.application.key_generator`)

Comment: Hmm, yes I do see it there. So what you're saying is when rails boots, it sets that ENV from the `credentials.yml.enc` file? Then... when it goes to encrypt a cookie or something it uses the ENV variable to read from?

Comment: The key used to encrypt credentials is different from the secret key base. The key on master.key is used to encrypt and decrypt all credentials. It does not replace the secret key base. So the secret key base should always be found in the environment (on a server at least). So to answer your question directly - the secret_key_base is always stored and referenced in the environment.

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear.. what I mean to ask is... when Rails rails boots, it basically decrypts credentials.yml.enc (with master key ENV or file) and then creates a NEW env variable for secret_key_base.... then, when it comes time to encrypt a cookie or session it reads the ENV variable. Is that correct? Ultimately what I care about is I want a guarantee that rails is properly loading my secret_key_base, and its not clear with secret_key_base appearing in 3 different locations.... (env, application.secrets and application.creds).

Comment: I have an important information that deals with finances and critical data, so im trying to make 100% sure that its properly setting secret_key_base in production. i see its in the ENV, and i see it in application.credentials, but its not in application.secrets. SO, for sanity, I wanted to know of a way so I can check that rails is properly seeing that key (ideally using the same strategy as the function which encrypts a cookie or something similar, that way I know taht function is actually working)